# best way to do list comprehension matching when there are multiple matches

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am extending a list called `projects` to include the project owner from another list. `Projects_with_owner` has two matches and is returning `None`. I assume because the element with `None` is the first match. I'd like to be able to include the one that does have a name if there is one. I could do this with sorting and making sure any with a name appear first, but am wondering if there is a better way.

```
Projects_with_owner = [['Project1', None],['Project1','Andrew']]

projects = [['Project1']]

for x in projects:
   x.extend([[y[1]] for y in Projects_with_owner if y[0] == x[0]][0])

print projects
```

Output:

```
[['Project1', None]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['Project1', 'Andrew']]
```

Comment: How would you handle it if there's more than one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
for project in projects:
    project.extend([orig_project[1] for orig_project in Projects_with_owner if
                    orig_project[1] is not None and
                    orig_project[0] == project[0]])
```

Note that this will give you

```
[['Project1', ['Andrew']]]
```

But will allow you to have more than one owner.

Comment: This doesn't include None when all the owners are None

Comment: @user3885927 is that the intended functionality? In which case `project.extend([ <existing list_comp> ] or [None])`

Answer (score 3):

```
for x in projects:
   x.extend([[y[1]] for y in Projects_with_owner if y[0] == x[0] and y[1] is not None][0])
```

Thit give exaclty what you want, but when there is only one match with None this doesn't extend your list. So maybe you should create a temporary list with all matches with project and next if there is more than one match, get these which have any owner.